# Can I get data into Salesforce Marketing Cloud from inhouse CRM?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

I use a customized in-house CRM and wish to pass that data into Salesforce Marketing Cloud (say data extensions) so I can use those segments to send emails to my customers. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest setting up some automated process in your in-house CRM to FTP flat files to the Import FTP directory in your SFMC account.  Once the files are getting transferred you can set up an [**Automation**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/) to fire an [**Import Activity**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/import_activity/) to get the data into a [**Data Extension**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/data_extensions_and_data_relationships/).

Here's a good overview: [**Importing Files Using ExactTarget’s Automation Studio**](http://www.degdigital.com/insights/exacttarget-training-automate-importing/)

Additional info about FTP File Locations: [**File Transfer Location**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/admin/file_transfer_location/)